# php If one out of many conditions is true or all is false

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

```
<?php
$input = '5' ;
$id = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

How to match if $input is in $id ?
How to do something if it is false (No match), like if $input='10' echo No match?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (in_array($input, $id)) {
    echo "Found element in array";
} else {
    echo "No match was found";
}
```

Explanation: the above snippet uses the built-in [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function, which checks if a value exists in an array. Then it's a simple matter to put it as a condition in an `if-else` statement. Always refer to the documentation first, many common problems dealing with arrays have existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To check if value is contained in array, you can use native PHP function [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if(in_array($input, $id)){
    echo 'Match';
}else{
    echo 'No match';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
<?php 

$input = '5' ;
$id = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

if (in_array($input, $id)) {
    echo "Match";
}
else {
    echo "No Match";
}

?>
```